# How can I register how many times a 'user' visits a website?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like parts of my website to be non-visible to the user if the user has accessed the website more than a certain number of times. The NY Times website has similar functionality.

I use react & firebase.

I did think about getting a user's IP address but my understanding is that measures geography, not necessarily a device.

P.S. If this question's unsuitable for SO, would you mind suggesting another forum, if you know of one, where it'd be more suitable?

Comment: So do you want to deny access like "too much try , it's anormal you are denied" or like "you have read 4 articles already, it's thee limit for today if you don't pay"?

Comment: Also, do you want to implement it on the web server, in php or with javascript? If you want it to work for sure you should implemont it on backend.

Comment: @Velome Yes to your first question. JS would be preferable (I've not used php so am hesitant to use that) & I'm not sure what implementing it on the web server means

Comment: FWIW, these aren't reliable and can be easily bypassed. For example in IOS Safari you can view in reader view and by pass any javascript restrictions. A combination server and client side (javascript) is the best solution.

Comment: This question asks for a solution without any apparent research or attempts, and would likely be denied on any site in the Stack Exchange network of sites.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have edited the question to show what research I did do. I know SO questions're meant to show research and knew my question would get flagged up but I don't know what search terms to use and so couldn't find any articles. If you were to pass on some terminology that I could use to research that'd be very helpful. And then I'm sure if I had a question I'd be able to pass your standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use js and the local storage of the client browser to do that the easy way (but it can be easily cheated on by cleaning history).

Just copy/past that in an .html file and it will work if you refresh more then 4 times :

```
<script>
    var dontDisplayPage = false;
    if  (localStorage.getItem('numberViews') === null){
      localStorage.setItem('numberViews', 1);
    }  else {
     localStorage.setItem('numberViews', parseInt(localStorage.getItem('numberViews'), 10) + 1);
    }
    if(parseInt(localStorage.getItem('numberViews'), 10)>4){
      dontDisplayPage = true;

    }
    if(dontDisplayPage) alert('too many views !');
</script>
```

Then looking at dontDisplayPage you know if you must display the page, here dontDisplayPage is true if page has been seen more 4 times.

Based on that you can hide the div containing the article for exemple and display a message.

Comment: Thanks @Velome. I should've mentioned I do use firebase as a backend. I presume more robust ways of achieving this task involves a backend?

Comment: Hey @tonitone120, thanks for your feedback. You are true, ideal would probably be to store ip in firebase with a connection timestamp but I have no expérience in firebase, sorry. I hope someone with firebasee skills can help you.